# How parse a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) file with Javascript to get the subject?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, cryptography, csr

I read a Certificate Signing Request in X.509 format. I have tried to parse it with the class X509Certificate from NodeJS 'crypto' library.
The input format is a string

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
MII....
-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

I want to get the subject from this certificate signing request (CN, emailAddress, C,...)

I tried the following code

```
const { X509Certificate } = await import('crypto');
const x509CSR = new X509Certificate(pem)
```

But the the following error is displayed:

> error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line

So I have tried another library called 'node-forge'.

```js
const { pki } = await require('node-forge');
x509CSR = pki.certificationRequestFromPem(pem);
```

But the the following error is displayed:

> Cannot read public key. OID is not RSA.

How to get the subject data from the certificate signing request in a NodeJS server?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jsrsasign library

```
npm install jsrsasign
```

```
const jsrsasign = require('jsrsasign');

const csr = new jsrsasign.asn1.csr.CSRUtil();
const csrObj = csr.pemToCSR(pem);

const subject = csrObj.subject;

console.log(subject);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your solution.

Thans you for your solution! The `jsrsasign` is the good library. But the version 11.1.0 implementation has a little bit changed. The following solution fixed the problem:

```js
const jsrsasign = await require('jsrsasign');
const csrUtil = jsrsasign.asn1.csr.CSRUtil;
const csrObj: ParamResponse = csrUtil.getParam(pem);
const subject = csrObj.subject;
console.log(subject)
```

Not that subject property has two properties: `str` and `array`. `str` is a stringified version of the subject and `array` is a properties list.